# C++ - invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int**'

Tags: c++

I have this following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void insert(int *a[], const int location, const int numofelements, const int value) {
    int n, b[10];
    a = *b;
    for (int n = numofelements; n > location; n--) {
        a[n-1] = a[n];
    }
    b[location] = value;
    *b = a;
}

int main() {
    int test[10] = [1,2,3,4,5];
    insert(test, 2, 5, 7);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cout << "test[" << i << "] = " << test[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the compiler says:

> [Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int**' [-fpermissive]
>   [Error] invalid conversion from 'int**' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
>   What does it mean? Thanks

Comment: `int *a[]` is actually `int **` (pointer to a pointer to int). Do you really meant that? You are passing `int[]` which is `int *`

Comment: You should open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how arrays decay to a pointer, in an expression, and then read it. You should find that to be a much more thorough and in-depth explanation than you can find in a brief answer on stackoverflow.com. This is a core C++ topic that must be understood in depth. Someone just telling you how to change the code won't help you next time, if you don't understand the underlying reason. There's also some evidence that this is not the real code you're compiling, because there should be many more compilation errors, elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Errors like this mean you are mixing integers and pointers to integers.
There is several cases in your code where that happens.

Lets look at  pointers in this example

```
//defining 
int a;     //int, a is an integer holding the value
int *b;    //*int, a pointer to an integer
int c[10]; //*int, arrays are to pointers to the first element with some different rules
int **d;   //**int, this is a pointer to a pointer
int *d[10];//**int, this is a pointer to a an array, and arrays similar to pointers
//using pointers
a = *b;    //* before a pointer returns its value
a = b[0];  //resolving the position of an array also returns its value
b = &a;    //& before a value returns the address
```

Lets take a look at your code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void insert(int *a[], const int location, const int numofelements, const int value) {
    int n, b[10];
    a = *b; //a is **int. *b means the first element so *b is an int.
    for (int n = numofelements; n > location; n--) {
        a[n-1] = a[n];
    }
    b[location] = value;
    *b = a; //a is **int. *b means the first element so *b is an int.
}

int main() {
    int test[10] = [1,2,3,4,5];
    insert(test, 2, 5, 7); //test is a *int, the function expects a **int
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cout << "test[" << i << "] = " << test[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Here is a tutorial on using pointers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointers.htm)

Comment: "arrays are really just pointers to the first element" ... well, not really-really, but practically (and often easier to think of them that way), since arrays decay into pointers as easily as popping a soap bubble.

Comment: @Eljay Good observation. I edited my response to be more accurate.